# argparse optional value for argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, argparse

I want to distinguish between these three cases:

- The flag is not present at all `python example.py`;
- The flag is present but without a value `python example.py -t`; and
- The flag is present and has a value `python example.py -t ~/some/path`.

How can I do this with Python `argparse`? The first two cases would be covered by `action='store_true'` but then the third case becomes invalid.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this with [`nargs='?'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> One argument will be consumed from the command line if possible, and
>   produced as a single item. If no command-line argument is present, the
>   value from default will be produced. Note that for optional arguments,
>   there is an additional case - the option string is present but not
>   followed by a command-line argument. In this case the value from const
>   will be produced.

Your three cases would give:

1. The `default` value;
2. The `const` value; and
3. `'~/some/path'`

respectively. For example, given the following simple implementation:

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-t', nargs='?', default='not present', const='present without value')

print(parser.parse_args().t)
```

You'd get this output:

```sh
$ python test.py
not present

$ python test.py -t
present without value

$ python test.py -t 'passed a value'
passed a value
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example of how to achieve that with parser.add_argument()?

Comment: @OmryYadan added, thanks for the feedback. Note that the linked docs contain a few more examples.