# Using docopt double dash option with optional parameter?

Tags: python, docopt

Using docopt, is there a way to make a double-dashed parameter that works with and without an equals sign?

I want both of the following commands to make --tls be true:

```
cmd --tls
cmd --tls=true
```

I seem to only be able to get one or the other to work by using

```
Options:
  --tls
```

or

```
Options:
  --tls=false
```

Separating them by a comma does not seem to work

```
Options:
  --tls, --tls=false
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/30896982/3001761 for how to do something similar in `argparse`; you may be able to work backwards from its help!

Comment: That would work: `--tls=(true|false)  Use TLS-encryption [default: true]`, but is propably not really what you want. Consider opening an [issue](https://github.com/docopt/docopt/issues).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I can't find a solution, but here's the best work-around I've got:

```
"""
Usage:
  test.py [tls [--true|--false]]
"""
from docopt import docopt
arguments = docopt(__doc__)
if arguments['tls'] and not (arguments['--true'] or arguments['--false']):
    arguments['--true'] = True
```

so argument options would be:

```
cmd
cmd tls
cmd tls --true
cmd tls --false
```

note that this is case sensitive, there may be bugs if you capitalize TLS: https://github.com/docopt/docopt/issues/460

another option:

```
"""
Usage:
    script.py [--tls [<tlsval>]]
"""
from docopt import docopt
arguments = docopt(__doc__)
assert arguments['<tlsval>'] in (None, 'true', 'false'), "invalid tls value -- expected true or false"
```

sorry for all the edits, but here's one more:

```
"""
Usage:
   script.py [--MAS|--GPI [RESEND|ADD|REMOVE|SKU]]

Options:
    --MAS                   only do MAS step
    --GPI                   only do GPI step, optionally specify ADD/REMOVE/SKU (default is RESEND)
        RESEND            only GPI, strategy=RESEND (default for --GPI)
        ADD               only GPI, strategy=ADD
        REMOVE            only GPI, strategy=REMOVE
        SKU               only GPI, strategy=SKU
"""
from docopt import docopt
arguments = docopt(__doc__)
strategy = [k for k in ['RESEND', 'ADD', 'REMOVE', 'SKU'] if arguments[k]]
strategy = strategy[0] if strategy else "RESEND" #resend is default
```

This one gets you the --argument but can't have the = after the --argument