# Why does adding the 'type' field to Argparse change it's behavior?

Tags: python, parsing, argparse

I have been following the example outlined in this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896982/argparse-optional-value-for-argument). But the behavior changes when I specify a type and I don't understand why?

```
parser.add_argument('--bar', nargs='?', default=None, const=True)
args = parser.parse_args(['--bar=False'])
#Prints False as a string
print(args.bar)


parser.add_argument('--bar', nargs='?', default=None, const=True, type=bool)
args = parser.parse_args(['--bar=False'])
#Prints True as a bool
print(args.bar)
```

It's not clear to me why in the first example 'False' overrides the const value of True but in the second example it does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type) is often helpful...

> By default, the parser reads command-line arguments in as simple strings. However, quite often the command-line string should instead be interpreted as another type, such as a float or int. The type keyword for add_argument() allows any necessary type-checking and type conversions to be performed.

Also, you should note that:

> The bool() function is not recommended as a type converter. All it does is convert empty strings to False and non-empty strings to True. This is usually not what is desired.

Answer (score -1):

When you say "type=bool", the criterion becomes "is it present or not".  You specified `--bar`, so it was present, and the result is True.  If you leave it out, the result will be False.

Usually, that's exactly what you want.  You don't want people to type `--bar==True` or `--bar==False`.  You want either `--bar` or no bar.